# enque css scripts in wrong order in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress childtheme. I have style.css in the childtheme and I am using this:
`wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style-bob', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );` to bring in the style.css from the parent - 2016 in this case. This is working fine as far as I can tell.

I now want to add a separate responsive css style sheet that is AFTER my childtheme/style.css (for development purposes)

If I add this to my function `wp_enqueue_style( 'responsive-bob', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/styles-responsive.css' );` it comes in BEFORE my childthemes css file.

How do i get the order right please?

Here's the whole function:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style-bob', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
   wp_enqueue_style( 'responsive-bob', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/styles-responsive.css' );
}
```

Comment: What is the order of these 2 functions in your `function.php` file?

Comment: added in the function

Comment: This should work just as you wanted, as far as I am concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "wait" for the child style to load and then load your stylesheet, ie, make your stylesheet dependant on the child style. The child style handle will be `twentysixteen-style`

You can do the following

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'responsive-bob', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/styles-responsive.css', array( 'twentysixteen-style) );
```